# Displaying post titles in a specific category in a shortcode (wordPress)

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

Trying to write my first short-code that displays all post-titles in a specific Category. But it is not displaying the actual results, just the short code.
Here is what I have so far in my child theme's `functions.php` file:

```
function posts_in_cat() {
echo '<ul>';
query_posts('cat=3'); while (have_posts()) : the_post();
echo ('<li><a href="' . the_permalink() . '">' . the_title() . '</a></li>');
endwhile;
wp_reset_query();
echo '</ul>';
}
add_shortcode( 'display_posts_in_cat', 'posts_in_cat' );
```

And then I am calling the short code, like so `[display_posts_in_cat]`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I try and learn this.

EDIT: I have gotten it to display but the link itself is being echo-ed in front of the title in text.  Also, it is not displaying more than 10 of the titles and I want it to display them all. Any ideas...?? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First and foremost, avoid using `query_posts()` – it's inefficient. Check out this [SO answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/1755/114696) for the skinny.

Additionally, shortcodes shouldn't make use of `echo` statements. Shortcodes only *return* text. Put simply, WordPress has PHP internally that says "when this specific shortcode is entered into the editor, replace it with the text returned from this function." Using `echo` causes you to immediately print those statements to the screen, rather than returning to WordPress so that it can continue with its regular process. More on the [WP Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_shortcode#Notes).

And, finally, shortcode functions require `$atts` as a parameter.

So, with all that said, here's how I would rewrite your function:

```
<?php

function posts_in_cat( $atts ) {
    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'cat' => '',
    ), $atts );

    if ( empty( $atts['cat'] ) ) {
        // If category provided, exit early
        return;
    }

    $args = array(
        'category' => $atts['cat'],
        // Disable pagination
        'posts_per_page' => -1
    );

    $posts_list = get_posts( $args );

    if ( empty( $posts_list) ) {
        // If no posts, exit early
        return;
    }

    $opening_tag = '<ul>';
    $closing_tag = '</ul>';
    $post_content = '';

    foreach ( $posts_list as $post_cat ) {
        $post_content .= '<li><a href="' . esc_url( get_permalink( $post_cat->ID ) )  . '">' . esc_html( get_the_title( $post_cat->ID ) ) . '</a></li>';
    }

    return $opening_tag . $post_content . $closing_tag;
}
add_shortcode( 'display_posts_in_cat', 'posts_in_cat' );
```

I'm just adding all of the content you were `echo`ing into a handful of variables, and then returning them, concatenated, at the end. Also, I added in an `if` statement to exit early if there aren't any posts in the category. That way you don't have an empty `<ul>` element cluttering up the page.

I've also escaped the outputs, which you can read about [on the Codex.](https://codex.wordpress.org/Validating_Sanitizing_and_Escaping_User_Data)

Comment: Awesome Leland. Much obliged. I have two follow-up questions: 1) For some reason it is displaying only the first 5, while I want them all to be displayed. 2.)  Can you please show me what to do if I want to add a parameter on the front end for the category id and it will pass that parameter to the function to display the titles of that category...?? `[display_posts_in_cat cat="3"]`

Comment: Thank you sir.  That did it.

Comment: Leland, sorry. I totally goofed.  How can I display the Category name at the top...??  That would seem the thing to do since the user would need to know what Category they are viewing.

Comment: Hey, just use `get_cat_name( $atts['cat'] );` where you want it to be.

Comment: Yes sir.  That worked well.  I should have figured it out myself but.....:(

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
 function posts_in_cat() { ?>
<ul class="posts">
<?php query_posts('cat=3&showposts=50'); while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
 ?>
    <li><a href='<?php the_permalink() ?>'><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
  </ul>

  <?php

    }
    add_shortcode( 'display_posts_in_cat', 'posts_in_cat' );
```